# Rebuild the Bootstrap Form Upload

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to rebuild the Bootstrap Form Upload field. The Reason is, because file upload field in Bootstrap is one component. You cannot split the file upload button and the file upload text.

[image: Image of the 2 Buttons]

The first Upload of the image is the Bootstrap's upload field. The second one is my upload button until now.

The HTML Code for the 2 Buttons

```
    <div class="mb-3 right-box">
      <label for="formFile">Binary Package</label>
      <input class="form-control formname" (change)="onFileSelected($event);  " type="file" id="formFile">
    </div>

    <label for="formFile">Source Package</label><br>
    <button id="formFile" (click)="binaryPackageInput.click()">
      Durchsuchen...
    </button>
    <input #binaryPackageInput class="form-control formname binary-package"
      (change)="onFileSelected($event); checkForm()" type="file" formControlName="fileControl">
    <span>{{this.fileName}}</span>
```

The CSS Code is until now:

```
input.binary-package {
  display: none;
}
```

How can I use the second upload button separate from text with the same styling as the first upload button? I used the same bootstrap classes.

I expected they look the same.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Comment: Why don't you use the bootstrap version then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something really close to my question. Here is the HTML:

```
  <label for="formFile">Source Package</label><br>
    <button class="form-control formname element1" id="formFile" (click)="binaryPackageInput.click()">
      Durchsuchen...
    </button>
    <input #binaryPackageInput class="binary-package" (change)="onFileSelected($event); checkForm()" type="file"
      formControlName="fileControl">

    <div *ngIf="this.fileName == ''" class="element2">
      Keine Datei ausgewählt
    </div>
    <span class="element2">{{this.fileName}}</span>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
input.binary-package {
  display: none;
}

#formFile {
  width: auto;
}

.element1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.element2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer? Please see [ask]  and take the [tour] if you're not sure how this site works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).